# How can I do to display an alert inside a jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this :

```
jQuery.each(....), function(....){

// I try to do alert("Hello"); but it does not work

}
```

And in the code is explained my problem, I can't achieve to do an alert which displays `"Hello"`. Do you have any ideas to solve this ?

Thank you !

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: Yeah, read the API for `each()`.  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each

Comment: Here you go: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: `alert()` works fine in jQuery, so long as your syntax is correct. Given the example here, you have several issues. I'd suggest explaining exactly what you're trying to do with the `each()` loop

Answer (score 0):

The 'each' method needs to be passed an object in the first instance:-

```
var myThings = [1,2, 'Red Herrring',32,59,81,3];
jQuery.each(myThings,function(ind,val){
    if (typeof val === 'string') {
        alert(val+' is a string');
    } else if (val <5) {
        alert(val+' is less than 5');
    }
})
```

Other methods to use each include passing it DOM elements using jQuery selectors:-

```
jQuery('input').each(function(){
    alert($(this).val())
})
```

'each' is a very well documented method, and, when I was learning, I found that W3 schools provides the best documentation for beginners.

Take a look here at their excellent reference guide: [W3 Schools Each Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/misc_each.asp) or better yet, visit the [jQuery API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each) to get a more thorough and detailed explanation of this method.

Please be free to ask any questions if you struggle or would like to achieve something specific!

Always happy to help a fellow coder :)

```js
var myThings = [1,2, 'Red Herrring',32,59,81,3];
jQuery.each(myThings,function(ind,val){
 if (typeof val === 'string') {
  alert(val+' is a string');
 } else if (val <5) {
  alert(val+' is less than 5');
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. In this case, go directly to the source, the jQuery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/each

Comment: Thanks for the advice Rory, that makes sense - I'll follow you're guidance on future answers. I opted for W3 since their literature is a little easier to follow for new developers than direct API documentation. I have updated my answer to reflect this! Kudos to you